# How to set environmental variable that can be get by System.getenv("name") in JAVA

Tags: java, android, macos, environment-variables, system

I get some environmental variables in this way:

```
String javaHome=System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
String androidHome=System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME");
```

However, it always return null to the androidHome.
I set it in ~/.bash_profile and it can be print in terminal by echo $ANDROID_HOME. 
Where should I set this variable?

Comment: If you see it with `echo $ANDROID_HOME` then you have done what is needed. Is this for android or the mac? They are quite different.

Comment: You may have set it but did you export it?

Comment: Use `env | grep ANDROID_HOME` to ensure it is actually exported. Doing `echo ANDROID_HOME` simply tells you it is set in the current shell -- which does not ensure it is exported to child processes.

Answer (score -1):

Try to verify that you really don't get it from the system environment by:
`Map env = System.getenv();` and checking all the keys in this map.